# addig p values to mutilevel correlations calculated with statsBy function in R

Tags: correlation, p-value, psych

I have the following code to calculate within- and between-person correlations of a multilevel dataset:

```
library(psych)

corrdata <- dat %>% 
  select(id, var1, var2)

between_within_corr <- statsBy(corrdata, group = "id", cors = TRUE,
  cor="cor", method="pearson", use="pairwise", poly=FALSE,
  na.rm=TRUE,alpha=.05,minlength=5,weights=NULL)

print(between_within_corr, short = FALSE)
```

How do i add p-values to the correlational coefficients?